# preg_replace integer and security

Tags: php, security, preg-replace

when I want to secure $_GET parameter I usually use:

```
$var = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_GET['var']))), ENT_QUOTES);
```

but if the $_GET parameter is only integer (only 0-9 characters) should I use:

```
$var = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(strip_tags(trim(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_GET['var'])))), ENT_QUOTES);
```

or simple:

```
$var = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_GET['var']);
```

and it will be still safe? Thank you for reply!

Comment: yes, `/\D/` should be safe to accept only integer numbers

Comment: Thank you for reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't accept and continue if variable validation failed: ( More secured! )

Validate `$_GET` parameter with `filter_var` function

```
if (!filter_var($_GET['var'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
    echo("Variable is an integer");
} else {
    echo("Variable is not an integer");
}
```